# Como faço para deixar a página aberta marcado no menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Por exemplo, nesse site quando você está em qualquer página fica marcado no menu com uma border-top:

http://w5.com.br/index.html

Gostaria de saber como eu faço isso, já tentei o visited no css e nada...

Comment: Seu site usa páginas dinâmicas (PHP ou coisa do tipo)? Se usa, um dos caminhos mais "universais" é aplicar uma classe no menu (ou no body)  ao gerar a página.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.active > a {
color:red;
}
```

É a melhor maneira

Answer (score 2):

Isso dá com javascript, pode fazer isso dependendo da página em que está:

ex HTML:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li class="home">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sobre_nos">
          <a href="#">Sobre nós</a>
      </li>
      <li class="serviços">
          <a href="#">Serviços</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS: Aqui é onde você coloca as propriedades que quer no item que estiver ativo (página onde está) no menu

```
.menu_active {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Agora vamos precisar de javascript. Se por exemplo estiver na página sobre noś:

JQUERY:

```
$('li.sobre_nos > a').addClass('menu_active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso é processado via css.
Adicione esse css na sua página e faça as adaptaçoes de IDs e Clases necessárias.
Nesse site demo o arquivo skin.css é que possue o css da página em questão.
O css é:

```
  /* NAVIGATION ------------------------------------------------------------*/
#nav > li > a {
  color: #dcd2be;
}
#nav > li:hover > a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}
#nav span:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -3px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-10px, -3px);
  -o-transform: translate(-10px, -3px);
  transform: translate(-10px, -3px);
}
#nav > li.current-menu-item > a,
#nav > li.current_page_item > a {
  border-top: 3px solid #009AD5;
}
#nav .sfHover ul {
  background: #f8f5f2;
}
#nav .sfHover ul li a {
  color: #333;
  font-size:13px;
}
#nav .sfHover ul li a:hover {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  color: #333;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que usar JavaScript para adicionar uma nova formatação ao seu menu.

Primeiro, você compara o valor do atributo `href` do link clicado com a `URL` atual, se forem iguais, então você adiciona a formatação com `CSS` ao menu correspondente.

O exemplo abaixo adiciona a classe `.active` ao clicar no link, mas não compara os valores de `href` com a `URL`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('.hmenu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents("li").addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active > a {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1" class="hmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle do exemplo acima.](https://jsfiddle.net/6put8tdx/)

[Exemplo comparando os valores de href com a URL](https://jsfiddle.net/t7cLy3s8/7/)

[Exemplo com um site de uma página só.](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

Answer (score 0):

cara eu ja fiz adicionando um id ao meu link segue  exemplo , ai em cada pagina html que eu estou eu adiciono o id e faço o css que eu quiser nesse id, ai se vc quiser mudar de cor por exemplo vc adiciona o id na respectiva pagina  , sem javascript .por exemplo na pagina home eu adiciono o id la , depois na pagina contato coloco esse mesmo id e tiro da pagina home , é uma maneira tbm quis ajudar

```
HTML 



<nav>
            <a href=""class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.jpg" alt=""><span>.</span></a>
             <label for="btn" class="icon">
                 <img src="../images/menu.png" class="imge" alt="">
             </label>
             <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="../vazz.html">Início</a></li>
                 <li>
                    <label for="btn-1" class="show">Jóias +</label> 
                 
                    <a id="ini"  href="">Jóias</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-1">
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="Aneis.html">Anéis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Aliancas.html">Alianças</a></li>
                    <li><a id="ini"  href="Braceletes.html">Braceletes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Brincos.html">Brincos</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Escapularios.html">Escapulários</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Pingentes.html">Pingentes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Pulseiras.html">Pulseiras</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Tercos.html">Terços</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Tornozeleiras.html">Tornozeleiras</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
</nav>

CSS

 #ini {
    color:white;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #edd02d, 0 0 6px #edb02d, 0 0 7px #ed9a2d, 0 0 8px #edd02d, 0 0 9px #edd02d, 0 0 10px #edd02d, 0 0 20px #edd02d, 0 0 10px #edd02d, 0 0 120px #edd02d, 0 0 130px #edd02d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #edd02d, 0 0 6px #edd02d, 0 0 7px #edd02d, 0 0 8px #edd02d, 0 0 9px #edd02d, 0 0 10px #edd02d, 0 0 20px #edd02d, 0 0 40px #edd02d, 0 0 120px #edd02d, 0 0 130px #edd02d;
   
    -webkit-animation: fluctuateBar 1s ease-in-out 1s;
    animation: fluctuateBar 1s ease-in-out 1s;
    }
```